figure of speech consisting in semantic inversion of roles
What is the name of the figure of speech consisting in semantic inversion of roles in a phrase?
Let me clarify with an example:

"Google doesn't find Chuck Norris: Chuck Norris finds Google".

There are many figures of speech here, but let's concentrate on the last part. The hyperbolic effect is enhanced by the fact that usually Google is used for searches, but, in this case, the subject and the objective are semantically switched.
Update:
As pointed out in this reply, the example I quoted looks like an antimetabole.
In effect, I wanted to keep only the last part of the sentence.
Let me try with a different example, from the poem "清平调·其一", by 李白. It starts with: "cloud" , "think", "cloths". At first any Chinese would read "[she is so beautiful that] the clouds make me think to her dresses". But the sentence can also be intended by switching the roles of the words: "[she is so beautiful that] the clouds [themselves] think to (would like to be) her dresses"

I think I follow the Chinese example, but it’s not very accessible. There is paraprosdokian, but I don’t think it’s exactly what you’re looking for. It doesn’t strike me as something that would necessarily have a term.

This is reminiscent of In Soviet Russia jokes, whose Wikipedia page links to Antimetabole:

In rhetoric, antimetabole [...] is the repetition of words in successive clauses, but in transposed order; for example, "I know what I like, and I like what I know". It is related to, and sometimes considered a special case of, chiasmus.

